# Name for a device that prevents the user from operating something incorrectly

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe a built-in device that prevents the user from incorrectly using/operating the thing it is on.

e.g. A tilt and turn window has a device which prevents the user from turning the handle further when the sash is open which could make it drop out and fall on the person.

It removes the possibility/opportunity for a user to do something wrong that would cause the window/object to fail.

I've found

- "Faulty operation lock"
- "anti-mishandling device"

I find them unclear, sound unnatural and only appear on the websites of foreign companies (hence bad translations).

"Fail safe device" is ok, but I find it too vague in this context.

Any ideas?

Comment: OP, if you **literally want the term for that thing IN A WINDOW**, you should ask that in the title.  it is a totally different question from the "general question".

Comment: just fyi a failsafe is different than an interlock.  An interlock prevents improper operation, a failsafe is designed so that failures are benign.  In your case, the window has not failed, it is just designed so that the window removal mode is not inadvertently entered.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The standard term used in all types of industry for this is an *[interlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlock_(engineering))*.

Interlocks can be implemented with software, electrical circuitry, or by mechanical means.

An example of a software interlock is a piece of code which checks a number of variables before allowing a certain action to execute.

An electrical interlock is usually a chain of sensors, switches, or relays that have to be set in the correct state to allow an operation to take place.  A common example is the sensors in elevator doors which prevent them from crushing a person when they sense someone is obstructing the door's automatic closing, or to prevent the doors from opening while the elevator is in motion or stopped between floors.

Mechanical interlocks are physical devices that prevent a mechanical system from entering an unwanted state.  Locking bearings and corresponding grooves in the gear selector shafts of a manual transmission, for example, prevent more than one gear from being selected at a given time.

The linked wikipedia article is not entirely accurate - it suggests the term is more specific than it actually is in practice.  For example, it says :

> For example, in a typical household microwave oven, the switch that disables the magnetron if the door is opened is not an interlock.

While I think in practice most engineers I know would certainly refer to such devices as interlocks, formally.  The [article's talk section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Interlock_(engineering)) has some good citations on the erroneous nature of that particular statement.

Comment: Awesome. Interlock does actually seem to be the perfect answer. Since it does not seem commonly used in windows, I'm going to stick with "Integral fail safe device" for now. I need something short that most everyone (e.g. regular people) will immediately understand. If you're interested, the exact thing I mean is pictured here: https://www.fensterhai.de/fileadmin/user_upload/Montageanleitung/Fenster_einbauen/fenster_einstellen_fehlbedienungssperre.png

Comment: @J... my experience with laser systems is that the same arrangement used in microwaves is always referred to as an interlock

Comment: @ChrisH Yep - anything Class IV will have a big, bold connector at the back labelled **INTERLOCK**.

Comment: @CMNEN - What does that thing do? Keeps you from being able to lock the door? I googled Fehlbedienungssperre and that's the video I got. Translated, it's "tampering device" (... *tamper proof* ?). But I'd assume it's a [*lockout*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockout-tagout) - for a lock - which is not the easiest thing to google.

Comment: For a canonical (and tragic) example of what happens when you omit a necessary interlock, search for Therac-25.

Comment: Have never heard this term used in my life, for a safeguard.

Comment: I may be wrong though.  It seems OP wants the specific term for the thing in  two-way windows.

Comment: @Fattie The window device was used as an example, but the question is clearly asking for the general term for this class of devices and this is certainly the correct answer to that question.  Whether I'd use it in the specific case of this window device for marketing literature targeted at the layman or regular consumer, and if not what a suitable description for that use-case would be, is a different question entirely.

Comment: Hi @J... .   "but the question is clearly asking for the general term"  I would say, my impression from reading CMNEN's various comments is that, in fact, what CMNEN really wanted to know is the specific term. (ie, CMNEN is literally working on a translation of something to do with windows).  But sure, on the face of it the title of the question is asking for the general term.

Comment: Hi @J... , welcome to the site, hope you enjoy it.  As you'll soon learn, it's unfortunately ubiquitous on ELU that folks ask "not what they mean"  :)

Answer (score 33):

The term used by the UK Government Health and Safety Executive is '**safeguards**'.

[Under 'What do I have to do ?'. . . Before you start.]

> Check that the machine is complete, with all **safeguards** fitted, and free from defects. The term ‘safeguarding’ includes guards, **interlocks**, two-hand controls, light guards, pressure-sensitive mats etc. By law, the supplier must provide the right safeguards and inform buyers of any risks ('residual risks') that users need to be aware of and manage because they could not be designed out

[HSE](http://www.hse.gov.uk/toolbox/machinery/safety.htm)

Comment: +1 The other answers might be the more technical term, but if you're looking for a more everyday term, this does nicely. As an American, this was the first word than came to my mind as well, so I'm certain that this isn't British specific.

Comment: As an everyday term this is fine, but a safeguard is a much broader term that includes all types of things that aren't interlocks (ie : that aren't things which prevent unwanted operation).  As example, things like shields, guards, and deflectors would be included - items that prevent fingers, hands, etc, from entering dangerous parts of the equipment (or to prevent work or swarf leaving the equipment at speed).  In these cases such items are needed precisely because the system is not interlocked and yet still relies on these physical barriers being installed for safety.

Answer (score 22):

There is an enormous variety of such devices, so the terminology varies depending on the particular usage, but here are some blanket terms:

### Interlock

A mechanical device or system architecture which requires some external set of requirements to be met in order to continue operation. In the example you gave, the device which prevents the handle from turning with the sash open is the **[interlock](https://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Interlock+(engineering))**. In this case, it is a *safety interlock*.

Source: I'm an aerospace engineer

A safety interlock can be a:

### Behavior-shaping constraint

These constraints **force** the user to make the device safe, often by way of an interlock. For example, in manual transmissions, there is an *interlock* which requires the driver to depress the clutch petal before starting the vehicle. This system is a **behavior-shaping constraint**, since the driver soon learns the process, and *instinctively makes the system safe*.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-shaping_constraint

### Poka-Yoke

Borrowed from Japanese, poka-yoke means "mistake-proofing" or "inadvertent error prevention". Specifically, it is a design wherein a system will *bring the operator's attention to improper conditions*. Thus, a poka-yoke doesn't actually prevent misuse like an interlock does, but instead relies on the operator to correct the condition.

For example: when keys are left in an automobile ignition, modern vehicles will make a persistent dinging sound when the driver door is open in an attempt to alert the driver, who might otherwise lock the keys in the vehicle.

This is in **contrast to an interlock**, which would instead prevent the doors from locking while the key is in the ignition.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poka-yoke

### Defensive-Design

This is the the general design principle which attempts to predict ways a device could be misused, and designing in a way which makes such misuse difficult or impossible.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_design

Comment: +1 for interlock (or interlocking)

Comment: A slang term for a specific kind of error-prevention device is [molly guard](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/molly-guard), which is probably easier explained by [some photos](https://www.google.com/search?q=button+mollyguard&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvzvKMksbXAhUH34MKHTsqAhMQsAQIOQ&biw=1309&bih=835) than a text explanation.  (It's a shield to _guard_ the button from _Molly_, who is liable to press it.)

Comment: Poka-yoke is the first thing I thought of as well.

Answer (score 16):

I agree with many of the other answers here in regards to a generic term, but there is a term that relates specifically to your examples that I have not seen.

### Stop

A "stop" is a piece on a mechanical device that prevents it from moving too far.  The window handle would have a stop that prevents you from turning it too far, and the hinge of the window itself would have a stop that prevents it from opening too far.  This is also used for a "door stop" that keeps the door from hitting a wall.

Comment: With the context given, this is the correct answer.

Comment: This is the term that I would understand, as someone whose only expertise with windows and doors is owning and operating them.

Comment: Yes, it's simply a stop or a "dog".

Comment: @Fattie, A dog ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog_(engineering) ) is a part that locks two parts together to synchronize movement or to stop movement.  A stop restricts from moving too far, but does not hold something in place.

Comment: hey @JPhi1618 - hmm, on say a ship (picture one of those arctic fishing boats that feature in TV documentaries these days!) .. imagine you have, say, something that slides along a bar.  a "dog" is nothing more than a projection of metal (like .. a dog, a penis) that the sliding thing runs in to and is thus stopped.  it's just a "stop", a stick of metal that sticks out.  (I've often wondered if a dog (ie, the opposite of a bitch) is so called because it has a dog, or if dogs are named after dogs!)  Anyway - you're totally correct, in engines and stuff a "dog" can kind of mean "gripper" - but -

Comment: ... such as in a dog clutch.  But then a dog clutch **is so called because**: a "normal' clutch just works by friction (it can still slide).  But if you add dogs (ie, projecting pieces of metal that look like penises) which lock in to holes, nothing can turn any more, it's a dog clutch.

Comment: Thats an interesting take on the etymology, and I'm not saying your wrong, but the wikipedia article mentions that it comes from a dog biting and latching on to something.

Answer (score 12):

Similar to Adrian's *safety feature* is [safety catch](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/safety-catch).

In British English at least, I'd be more likely to refer to the specific button or switch on a device as "the safety catch" instead of the "the safety feature". In the US, in relation to guns, I believe this is often just shortened to "the safety".

Comment: Thanks. in AE it is definitely for firearms primarily. Thanks for the input, I didn't know there was any other meaning of it. However, the device I mean is integral, it's not a button or switch the user even sees, much less operates.

Comment: @CMNEN - Then it's just an integral safety (device). Most equipment in your home comes equipped with, or is protected by, multiple ***safeties*** (North American: short for *safety lock* – Google). E.g., the T&P valve on your HW tank, or the limit switches and the fuse in your furnace, and every other CB or fuse in your house.

Comment: I think that's a bit different - it's something you **actively turn on** for safety. I believe the OP is asking about a safeguard, a stop.

Comment: I may be wrong about that - maybe that's exactly what you call the stop on a window that stops it going out to far .. the safety stop .. "safety latch" maybe??

Answer (score 4):

Although it sounds a bit pejorative, one example is *fool-proof*.

In the early days of computer design, peripherals had to be plugged into a PC using specific outlets.  Mouse, keyboard, printer, etc each had ts own outlet.  If the user plugged any device into the wrong place, damage could occur.
At first some manufacturers color-coded the cords, but this did not **prevent** user errors.  Finally they changed the shapes of the plugs; making it impossible for the user to miss-configure the setup.

They *fool-proofed* the design.

Comment: Thanks. "Fool proof" is the right direction and a great example, but it doesn't quite capture the German idea I'm trying to explain succinctly.

Answer (score 2):

The [interlock](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/418834/revisions) answer is a good one. It has connotations of a connection between two systems, to stop them both being in conflicting states. It is also a fairly technical word for a lay audience.

A more passive device might be called a *guard*, which Google defines for me as "a device worn or fitted to prevent injury or damage."

Blade guards, sneeze guards, [molly guards](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/molly-guard), finger guards - these are all "devices that prevents the user from incorrectly using/operating the thing it is on." without being interlocks.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a single word but *safety feature* could be used to describe the device in your tilt and turn example.

Comment: This is perfectly correct.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going with "Integral fail-safe device" which is still somewhat vague but comes closest to the idea without being a full sentence.

Comment: Fail safe means the device ends up in a safe state when it fails, e.g. a fuse that cuts power if it overloads, or a nuclear reactor that drops control rods into the fissile material to prevent meltdown if coolant stops flowing. They do not limit the capacity of a user to do something they shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

I see no one has mentioned the informal term **idiot-proof** yet. This is to be distinguished from *fool-proof*, a term that does not apply here.

A fool-proof system cannot be cheated (fooled) by someone trying to cheat it.

An idiot-proof system on the other hand, is designed to be robust to unintentional errors committed by an intended user.

Comment: In tech, I have heard the term 'marketing-proof'... :P

Comment: I believe, the OP is asking for the term for the "thing" that is indeed there to idiot-proof the device.

Answer (score 0):

What about "Precaution System or Unit" ?

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't really sound like English nor is the meaning clear.

Answer (score 0):

I immediately think of:

> [**governor**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/governor) (n.)
>
> **a** : an attachment to a machine (such as a gasoline engine) for automatic control or limitation of speed
>
> **b** : a device giving automatic control (as of pressure or temperature)
>
> Mechanical sense of "self-acting regulator" is from 1819. ([*Etymonline*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/governor))